# jquery how to get Name of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

im searching for the Element whicht Provides the Name of a Parent. This:

```
            $('.Item').click(function(){
                var a = $(this).parent();
                alert(a[0].tagName);
            });
```

just says "DIV", but I need the real name of a Element. Thanks

Comment: That is because it returns an object. If you want a class or an ID specify.

Comment: div elements don't have a name attribute, but most browsers will let you add one. Because it's a non-standard attribute, you'll need to use jQuery's *attr* or the DOM *getAttribute* method to get it: `this.parentNode.getAttribute('name')`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following (Alerts the tag name, and then the Real Name) :

I used `$(a[0]).attr('name');`

e.g.

```
$('.Item').click(function() {
        var a = $(this).parent();
        alert(a[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()); //Tag Name

        alert($(a[0]).attr('name')); //Attribute (real) name
        //OR
        alert(a.attr('name')); //Attribute (real) name
    });
```

Comment: Use a.attr('name') instead of $(a[0]).attr('name')

Comment: Thanks Darm Ret, I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var a = $(this).parent().attr('name');
```

Comment: I think he means div,input,span,nav... rather than name="this"

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.Item').click(function(){
            var a = $(this).parent();
            alert(a.attr('name'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/R833t/1/

```
$('.Item').click(function(){
                var a = $(this).parent();
                alert(a.attr('name'));
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use plain Javascript for this - in this case it's even simpler (I think):

```
$('.Item').click(function() {
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var tagName = parent.tagName; // tag name, like 'div', 'a', etc...
    var name = parent.name // value of the 'name' attribute
});
```

My source: [JavaScript DOM](http://krook.org/jsdom/). Take a look at it, and help yourself.

Edit: wrapped code inside the click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

var a = $(this).parent();
        alert(a[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()); //Tag Name

```
    alert($(a[0]).attr('name')); //Attribute (real) name
    //OR
    alert(a.attr('name')); //Attribute (real) name getting issue on this code
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the attribute "name" you should use .attr()
`$('.Item').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).parent();
    alert(a[0].attr("name"));
    });`