# Can't read the NodeName of a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to build a script which recognizes the index of an (unspecified) element within its parent element with an simple `mouseclick`. It's possible that the clicked element is a `span`, `div`, `li` or any other element.

Problem is that I am not able to retrieve the TagName / NodeName of the parent element because I always get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`

My HTML looks like that:

```
<body>
    <span id="test1">
        <div>test</div>
    </span>
    <div id="test2">
        <div>eins</div>
        <div>zwei</div>
        <div>drei</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My function looks like that:

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    var child = evt.target.tagName;
    var parent = $(evt).parent();
    console.log(parent[0].nodeName);
});
```

According to [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840291/jquery-how-to-get-name-of-parent) thread this should be right, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to build a script which recognizes the index of an (unspecified) element within its parent ...

So you just need to use [$.fn.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method with `evn.target` which points to clicked element:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    var index = $(evt.target).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="test1">
    <div>test</div>
</span>
<div id="test2">
    <div>eins</div>
    <div>zwei</div>
    <div>drei</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that -

```
$(evt).parent();
```

Should be -

```
$(evt.target).parent();
```